# PayPal Invoicing API - VALIDATION_ERROR

Tags: paypal

I am developing an application that communicates with PayPal's API to create invoices.

This is my Request Body:

```
{
  "detail": {
    "currency_code": "USD",
    "note": "Thank you for using my services!"
  },
  "invoicer": {
    "name": {
      "given_name": "Shreyas",
      "surname": "Ayyengar"
    },
    "email_address": "{email}",
    "website": "{website}"
  },
  "primary_recipients": [
    {
      "billing_info": {
        "email_address": "{client_email}"
      }
    }
  ],
  "items": [
    {
      "name": "{invoice_name}",
      "description": "{invoice_description}",
      "quantity": "1",
      "unit_amount": {
        "currency_code": "USD",
        "value": "{invoice_amount}"
      },
      "tax": {
        "name": "PayPal Service Tax",
        "percent": "7.25"
      }
    }
  ],
  "configuration": {
    "partial_payment": {
      "allow_partial_payment": false
    },
    "allow_tip": true
  }
}
```

While there are placeholders like: {client_email}, I can guarantee that they are replacing properly and as expected.

However I'm thrown a `VALIDATION_ERROR` which I am not able to understand: `{"name":"VALIDATION_ERROR","message":"Invalid request - see details.","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/invoicing/#errors","details":[{"field":"merchant_info","issue":"cannot be null."},{"field":"items[0].unit_price","issue":"null"}]}`

From what I can minimally understand, this error says that I have missing information like `Items[].unit_price` and `merchant_info` however I have no idea where this is supposed to be in my Request Body. I am following the direct documentation[here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/regional/th/invoicing/basic-integration/) but I cannot see anything that mentions `unit_price` or `merchant_info`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Submit your request to the correct API endpoint, `https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/invoicing/invoices`

Note the major version number. See the [Invoicing API reference](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/invoicing/v2/#invoices_create) for details.

Comment: thank you for that. It has fixed my previous error, but now I am getting a `{"name":"AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE","message":"Authentication failed due to invalid authentication credentials or a missing Authorization header.","links":[{"href":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/#error","rel":"information_link"}]}`

Not sure how to fix use because I'm sure that my client ID, Secret, and Token are valid

Comment: Only use a sandbox client_id and secret with sandbox endpoints.   Only use a live client_id and secret with live endpoints (that do not contain `sandbox.`)

Comment: Sorry I did not understand what you meant by this

Comment: Use credentials for the correct environment.

Comment: Is my environment `live`?

Comment: Not unless you are using a live API endpoint or trying to use live credentials

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245134/discussion-between-shreyas007-and-preston-phx).